# Pull email address from survey results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, survey

One of my survey questions will be yes/no type.  What I need to so is to be able to capture the email accounts of all those who answer yes in my survey.  Currently, when I export to excel, I am only able to see the name of the submitter.  Since this is going to a very large group, I want to save the manual work of looking up the emails from my work directory.

I guess alternatively I can create one more field in the survey to ask respondents to enter their email or user ID, but I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid this.

Thanks!

Comment: All the survey respondents are registered users on your windows network?

Answer (score 2):

Go into **List Settings** and click either **Created By** or **Modified By** to edit the column. At the very bottom under **Additional Column Settings** you can change the **Show field** dropdown to **Work email** instead of the default which is **Name (with Presence)**.

Make sure this field (Created By/Modified By) is added to your view and when you export to Excel, you'll have the users' email addresses.

(Tested with SharePoint 2013, on premise.)

Comment: I also use SP2013 on-premise. I created a list with "survey" template. I only find "Created" and "Modified" (the time) column and cannot find the field "Created By". Is it hided by some settings?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do this for a **Survey** app today which doesn't have the same **Additional Column Settings** like a custom List survey which is the other answer provided. I did finally figure it out, so I wanted to share my findings.
Since it is a Survey, in order to edit the **Created By** field, you have to do the following:

1. Open a SharePoint Site……Open the Survey List.
2. Find the ListID from the URL like `List=%7BF2141E9F%2D8EA2%2D42EE%2DA965%2D52F1D7362066%7D`
3. Change the URL in the browser as `http : //SiteName/_layouts/FldEditEx.aspx?List=%7BF2141E9F%2D8EA2%2D42EE%2DA965%2D52F1D7362066%7D&Field=Author`  [Note: The `'&Field=Author'` at the end changes the **Created By** alias field]
4. This brings up '**Edit Question**' for '**Created By**' field. Under '**Show Field**:', choose the alternative user representation you would like shown such as '`**Work Email**`' or '**User name**'.
5. Select 'OK' to save.

This also allows for using the 'export' option on the survey to get something besides 'name' to show up in the generated Excel file.

Options for the field include:
[image: 'Created By' field options]